# All stlyes in css

Tags: css

In .Net, all styles are not listed in corresponding controls and html tags. For example, the style "WORD-BREAK","WORD-WRAP" etc. Any site which lists all styles available to all tags and controls ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp) is a great place to start learning CSS.

The [official specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/) is another place to look.

Comment: But here, all the styles will not be shown. Styles like "WORD-BREAK","WORD-WRAP" etc. are not shown. i got this link. This shows all styles including the styles which does not show in Visual Studio, but we can use. 

http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/css/propindex/all.htm

Is there any other sites like the above, which lists all styles available

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at w3schools. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_reference_atoz.asp
But remember that there are also styletags specific to a certain browser (like the mozilla tags).

As far as I know Visual Studio shows the tags which are compatible with all browsers (and that might be the reason why you are missing some items).

Also, you can apply all style tags to all HTML tags (you can assign font to an img tag), but they might not give you the effects you are hoping, but the beauty of CSS is that you can assign any style to any tag (and if you are embedding tags in eacht other it will inherit the style, so for example assigning a list-style to a div might not look usefull, but is allowed and will cause all lists in that div to look the same, ofcourse this can be done in various other ways).

Comment: i got this link. This shows all styles including the styles which does not show in Visual Studio, but we can use.

http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/css/propindex/all.htm